# 2 wire light fixture with black and green wires

Tags: light-fixture

wife bought an old light fixture for kitchen with only black and green wires bonded with rubber sheathing. Do i simply cut and cap the white common wire from the house feed? Of course it has 5 lights and a plastic shell,will try to post pics

Comment: Never play "match the color".  That is going to end badly unless you have the expertise to know what the wires do, and re-mark their colors to match their function.

Answer (score 3):

No - don't confuse old fixture colors with current wiring colors.

If your fixture only has 2 wires, then black to black, white to what's left.

Use a metal box and attach the ground to the box.

Comment: It's going in a 20 year old home with a plastic box and the fixture is plastic, should i still switch boxes?

Comment: Hmm.  There certainly doesn't seem to be much point to changing boxes to metal if the fixture is plastic.